# Jquery keyup function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the `$(':text').keyup(function() {` I tried changing the :text into :number doesn't work only works if I remove the `&& $('#number').val() != ""`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(event) {  
$(':text').keyup(function() {
    if($('#input').val() != "" && $('#number').val() != "" 

    ){
       $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
       $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);   
    }
});});
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<form><input type=text id='input'>
<input type=number id='number'><br>
<input type=button id='submit' value='submit'>
    </form>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LaLL0v6a/

Comment: use prop - http://jsfiddle.net/LaLL0v6a/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny That doesn't seem to work for me (Chrome). The submit stays disabled.

Comment: @Mike you need to enter data in the number field first then in the text field because the keyup is registered to only first field

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ah, gotcha. In that case, it would probably be better to use `:input` or something that would match both elements.

Comment: @Mike or if you want to be specific use the ids as I have given in the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. You are registering the keyup handler to only the first input element, not the second one because its type is number
2. Use .prop() to set the disabled state
3. If you enter a non numerical value in number field then it will remain disabled because .val() will return an empty string

so

```js
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('#input, #number').keyup(function () {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', $('#input').val() == '' || $('#number').val() == "");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id='input' />
<input type=number id='number' />
<input type=button id='submit' value='submit' disabled />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Change** `$(':text')` **to**  `$('input[type="text"]')`

Answer (score 2):

**Use**

```
$('#input').keyup(function() {
```

**or**

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
```

**instead of**

```
$(':text').keyup(function() {
```